# spresense LTE拡張ボードでFTPクライアント通信を行う方法

Tags: spresense, ftp

Spresense本体ボード+ LTE拡張ボードの構成で、SpresenseのFTPクライアントから、ネットワークサーバー上のFTPサーバへアクセス(ファイル書き込み、ファイル読み出し）を実現したいと考えています。
「Networkチュートリアル」には、「FTPサンプルアプリケーション」の実例が掲載されていますが、WiFi環境(IDY Wi-Fi Add-on Board iS110B搭載)が前提となっています。
そこで、このFTPサンプルアプリケーションをWiFi通信からLTE-M通信へ変更する方法を教えていただけないでしょうか。
LTE-M関連の設定は自己解決するとして、WiFiもLTEにはTCP/IP通信レベルで互換があると思うので、何かの設定などで実現できると助かるのですが。
「LTE-M経由でIoTデータをファイルサーバーへ定期的にUPしたい」、というのが最終目標です。

Answer (score 0):

ドンピシャリという回答ではないですが、次の実装が参考になると思います。

https://github.com/sonydevworld/spresense/tree/master/examples/lte_http_get

ここで、wget_initialize でHTTPサーバーとやりとりを行っているのですが、grep で引っ掛けてみた所、次のところに実装がありました。

https://github.com/sonydevworld/spresense-nuttx-apps/blob/new-master/netutils/webclient/webclient.c
注意）Spresense SDK をダウンロードすると spresense/sdk/apps/netutils 以下に展開されます。このあたりちょっと分かりにくい・・・

webclinet.c の中を見てもわかるように、こちらはよくある socket を使ったプログラミングになってます。

ですので、lte_http_get サンプルの中のLteのコネクション部分をもってきて、wget_initialize(), wget() の部分をFTPに入れ替えればよいかと思います。思いっきり端折ったコードを書くとこんな感じでしょうか…。

```
int main(int argc, FAR char *argv[])
{
  ... 省略 ....

  app_mq_create(APP_MQUEUE_NAME);
  lte_initialize();
  lte_set_report_restart(app_restart_cb);
  lte_power_on();
  lte_set_report_localtime(app_localtime_report_cb);
  lte_radio_on_sync();

  /* Set the APN to be connected. */
  ...　省略 ...
  lte_activate_pdn_sync(&apnsetting, &pdn);
  app_show_pdn(&pdn);
  data_pdn_sid = pdn.session_id;

  ...　省略 ...

  /* ↓ここにFTPのソケットコード実装を書く↓ */

　FTP初期化
　FTPサーバーに接続
　FTPサーバーにデータ送信

  /* ↑ここにFTPのソケットコード実装を書く↑ */

  lte_deactivate_pdn_sync(data_pdn_sid);
  lte_radio_off_sync();
  lte_power_off();
  lte_finalize();
  app_mq_delete(APP_MQUEUE_NAME);

  return 0;
}
```

FTPクライアントのソケット実装は、次のサイトとかが参考になるかと。ご参考まで。

[http://x68000.q-e-d.net/~68user/net/c-ftp-1.html](http://x68000.q-e-d.net/%7E68user/net/c-ftp-1.html)

Answer (score 0):

SpresenseのSDKで、
sdk/configs/examples/ftp/defconfig と
sdk/configs/examples/lte_http_get/defconfig
を比較すると、FTPクライアントに関わる部分の違いは、
+EXAMPLES_FTPC=y
+NETUTILS_FTPC=y
だけのようです。

ビルド時のコンフィグで、
`$ ./tools/config.py examples/lte_http_get`
とした後、
`$ make menuconfig`
で、メニューコンフィグを開いて、

"Application Coonfiguration" -> "Network Utilities"
の中にある、
"FTP client"
を有効にするのと、

"Application Coonfiguration" -> "Examples"
の中にある、
”FTP client example"
を有効にすれば、
NuttShellで、ftpcを使うことが出来ると思います。

LTEボードを持っていないので、
試せてはいないので、参考でしかないですが、
試してみてください。

Answer (score 0):

2つ目にいただいた回答の通り、lte_http_getをベースに、次の2つのコンフィグを有効にして、
　"Application Coonfiguration" -> "Network Utilities" -> "FTP client"
　"Application Coonfiguration" -> "Examples"-> ”FTP client example"
あと、追加でLTE daemonも有効にすることで、LTE-M経由でインターネット上のFTPサーバーへの通信（put/getとも）ができました！
ただ、１つ課題が残っています。
ftpc "**.**.**.**" とIPアドレス直打ち（FTPサーバーのグローバルIPアドレス）では成功するのですが、ドメイン名(例：aaa.bbb.com)にて接続しようとするとエラーになって接続できませんでした。
nsh>ftpc ftp://aaa.bbb.com
nsh>ftpc aaa.bbb.com
のどちらで実行してもエラーになります。
サンプル"lte_http_get"は、"http://www.example.com"のようにドメイン名指定で問題なく動作できているため、DNSサーバー設定（下記）はこのままでも良さそうに思えます。
+NETDB_DNSCLIENT=y
+NETDB_DNSCLIENT_MAXRESPONSE=176
+NETDB_DNSCLIENT_NAMESIZE=255
+NETDB_DNSSERVER_IPv4ADDR=0x8080808
そこで、コンフィグレーションにてLTEデバッグを有効にしてエラー出力すると下記のように出力されました。
nsh> ftpc ftp://aaa.bbb.com
[ERR] getsockname_request:134 API command response is err :128.
[ERR] 2343 altcom_getsockname() failed = -128
Failed to connect to the server: 9

FTPサーバー(ftp://aaa.bbb.com)へは、PCからアクセスできています(SSLなしです）。
何か設定が間違っているのでしょうか。それとも、SpresenseのFTP client sampleは、IPアドレス指定しか動作しないという制約があるのでしょうか。
（WiFi Add-on Boardを所有していないため、WiFi経由でFTP client + ドメイン指定にて動作確認はできていません。インターネット上のFTPサーバーのIPアドレスが変更されることがあるため、ドメイン名にてアクセスを実現したいです。

Comment: 質問時とは異なるIDですが、質問者ご本人でしょうか？ヘルプページを参考にアカウントのマージを検討してください。 - [間違えてアカウントを 2 件作成してしまいました。どうしたらマージできますか？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts)

Comment: また、当初の質問が他のユーザーからの回答で解決した場合には、[自分の質問に誰かが回答してくれたらどうしたらいいですか？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) を参考に対応を行ってください。追加で出てきた新しい課題については、別の質問として投稿し直してください。

Answer (score 0):

お二方に加えて、気になるポイントを2つコメントします。

1. NuttXのFTPクライアントサンプルはIPアドレス指定にしか対応していない
2. 同サンプルはコンフィグによって指定できるIPアドレスのタイプが異なる

1点目についてですが、現在のFTPクライアントサンプルはヘルプテキスト通りIPアドレス指定にしか対応していないようです。
ですので、サンプルをそのまま使う場合はIPを事前に調べてから

```
  nsh> ftp xx.xx.xx.xx
```

のようにIP直指定してあげるしかなさそうです。
アプリケーションを書く場合には、getaddrinfoなどの関数を使用してドメインをIPに変換してあげる必要があります。

2点目ですが、FTPクライアントサンプルのコードを確認してみましたが、コンフィグによって指定するIPアドレスのタイプ(IPv4/IPv6)を切り替えているようです。
現在、examples/lte_http_get では、IPv4とIPv6共に有効になっているため、このサンプルではIPv6アドレスを指定してあげなければなりません。
これを回避する方法としては、

```
./tools/config.py -m
```

でmenuconfigを開いたのち

```
Networking Support --->
  Internet Protocol Selection  --->
    IPv6 ★このチェックを外す
```

という様なコンフィグ変更をする必要があるようです。

以上のような変更を加えて、私の環境ではFTPクライアントがLTE通信で確認できました。

(lte_daemon start/ifup eth0 を行うと、ftp xx:xx:xx:xx で動作を確認することができます。)

参考になればうれしいです。